# How to import variables from another file AFTER the program has started in python?

Tags: python, import

I want to create a program that makes the user select a file, and that file will contain a series of variables (like dictionaries and lists) that the program will use. Now, I know there's the `import file` function but I can't use it because that's supposed to be at the beginning of the program (the user has to select which program wants to load first). The only step that's left in my program is the one that loads the variables, I know how to do the rest. Could anyone help me? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use

```py
with open(file, "r") as f:
    data = f.read().splitlines()
```

to read the data, assuming every variable is on its own line. This will read in all variables in the file `file` as a list called `data` containing each file line as one entry.

Note that this will read all variables in as strings, so you may have to cast to different types before actually using the values.

Comment: I see how that could help me, but that leads to a question. What I have is a program that writes a .py document with dictionaries and lists, and these can be very large, depending on the user intentions. If the dictionary is to large, it will use more than one line (when I open the created file with my notepad, it uses more than one line). Wouldn't that mess up with my program? I mean, if I split the file according to the lines, wouldn't that split the variables?

Comment: If you create the variables in python and save them as is, it shouldn't automatically add any line breaks and reading them in line wise should still work. Many editors add automatic line wrapping when viewing long lines for better readability, you could try to find whether your editor does that and if the line breaks are still there when you deactivate that feature.